# How do I print a #defined constant in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb, c-preprocessor

As per subject.

I have some constants hash defined like so:

```
#define CONST 40
```

I've set a breakpoint in my program. How do I print the value of that constant? (I know I can just look at the source code, but I want to be sure of it)

Comment: In general, this is why you shouldn't use `#define` for defining numeric constants.  For integer constants, use `enum` instead.

Comment: Oh, I was using it for error codes, and since they're from different files, I didn't want to have to dig through every one of them to find what they are

Comment: You may also need to build with `-g3`. `-g3` includes items like symbolic constants.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
help macro
```

You must compile with the -g3 flag for it to work and start your program before the macros are loaded.

In your case:

```
info macro CONST
```

or

```
macro expand CONST
```

More info: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html