# thread-aware gdb for the Linux kernel

Tags: debugging, gdb, linux-kernel, kernel

I am using gdb attached to a serial port of a virtual machine to debug linux kernel.

I am wondering, if there is any patches/plugins which can make the gdb understand some of linux kernel's data structure and make it "thread aware"?

By that I mean under gdb I can see how many kernel threads are there, their status, and for each thread, their stack information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**libvmi**

https://github.com/libvmi/libvmi

This project does "LibVMI: Simplified Virtual Machine Introspection" which sounds really close.

This project in particular https://github.com/Wenzel/pyvmidbg uses libvmi and features a demo video of debugging a Windows userland application form inside it, without memory conflicts.

As of May 2019, there are two limitations however as of May 2019, both of which could be overcome with some work: https://github.com/Wenzel/pyvmidbg/issues/24

- Linux memory parsing is not yet complete
- requires Xen

The developer of that project also answered further at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369454/895245

Implementing it with those libraries would be in my opinion the best way to achieve this goal today.

**Linaro `lkd-python`**

First, this Linaro page claims to have a working setup: https://wiki.linaro.org/LandingTeams/ST/GDB that allows you to do usual thread operations such as `thread`, `bt`, etc., but it relies on a GDB fork. I will test it out later. In 2016, https://youtu.be/pqn5hIrz3A8 says that the implementation was in C, not as Python scripts unfortunately, which would be better and avoid forking. The sketch for lkd-python can be found at: https://git.linaro.org/people/lee.jones/kieran.bingham/binutils-gdb.git/log/?h=lkd-python

**Linux kernel in-tree GDB scripts + my brain**

I then tried to see what I could do with the kernel in-tree Python scripts at v4.17 + some manual intervention as a prototype, but didn't quite get there yet.

I have tested using this [highly automated QEMU + Buildroot setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/39762d2f158789a399a2ef962703c43a5339f308#lx-ps).

First follow the procedure I described at: [How to debug the Linux kernel with GDB and QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642) to get GDB working.

Then, as described at: [How to debug Linux kernel modules with QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607538/how-to-debug-linux-kernel-modules-with-qemu/44095831#44095831) run GDB with:

```
gdb -ex add-auto-load-safe-path /full/path/to/linux/kernel
```

This loads the in-tree GDB Python scripts from `scripts/gdb`.

One of those scripts provides:

```
lx-ps
```

which lists all threads with format:

```
0xffff88000ed08000 1 init
0xffff88000ed08ac0 2 kthreadd
```

The first field is the address of the `task_struct` struct, so we can see the entire struct with:

```
p (struct task_struct)*0xffff88000ed08000
```

which should in theory allow us to get any information we want about the process.

Now I wanted to find the PC. For ARM, I've seen: [Find program counter of process in kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030910/find-program-counter-of-process-in-kernel) and I tried:

```
task_pt_regs((struct thread_info *)((struct task_struct)*0xffffffc00e8f8000))->uregs[ARM_pc]
```

but `task_pt_regs` is a `#define` and GDB cannot see defines without `-ggdb3`: [How do I print a #defined constant in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934006/how-do-i-print-a-defined-constant-in-gdb) which are apparently not set?

**The dream: a GDB Thread Aware Python extension API**

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/gdb/2017-March/046559.html

Currently the only way to do it with python I think would be to implement a custom version of every command you want to support:

- xxx-threads: list
- xxx-thread: change current thread
- xxx-p: print current thread

But what we really want is to have a GDB api where a python script provides only the minimal necessary parameters for all GDB commands to just work transparently (`thread info`, `thread N` and so on).

The API would basically only need to:

- list threads
- change to thread
- provide registers of a given thread

I think, and everything else might could just work based on those. Then the Linux kernel would be able to maintain its own in-tree Python provider that works for the Linux kernel, and similarly for any other operating systems.

Comment: Another workaround for the macro issue is 
[./scripts/gdb/linux/constants.py.in][1]

You could then write a python helper to perform these conversions, but be wary - as they will likely be version and/or architecture specific. And I believe the thread_info structures have moved recently to improve security.

[1]: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/gdb/linux/constants.py.in

Answer (score 2):

[pyvmidbg](https://github.com/Wenzel/pyvmidbg) developer here.

I will add some clarifications:
yes the goal of the project is indeed to have a cross-platform, guest-aware GDB stub.

Most of the implementation is already done for Windows, where we are aware of processes and their threads context.
It's possible to intercept a specific process (`cmd.exe` in the demo) and singlestep its execution (this is limited to 1 process with 1 thread for now), as well as attaching to a new process's entrypoint.

Regarding Linux, I looked at the internals and the resources that I could find, but I'm lacking the whole picture to figure out how I can:
- intercept a task when it's being scheduled (`core/sched.c:switch_to()` ?)
- read the task state (Windows's `KTRAP_FRAME`  equivalent for Linux ?)

I asked a question on SO, but nobody answered :/
[Linux context switch internals: how does a process goes back to userland after the switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771450/linux-context-switch-internals-how-does-a-process-goes-back-to-userland-after-t)

If you can help with this, I can guide you through the implementation :)

Regarding the hypervisor support, only Xen is fully supported in the Libvmi interface at the moment.
I added a section in the README to describe where we are in terms of VMI APIs with other hypervisors.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think GDB understands kernel data structures, that would make them version dependent. GDB uses [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) for gathering information on any running process.

That's all I know :(