# Find program counter of process in kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, program-counter

I'm trying to track the value of the PC of a particular process within the kernel.
To do this, I looked at the kernel source and figured out that the pc is being stored inside `task_struct->stack` and that to make sense of the stack, I need to type cast it into `struct thread_info *`.
Therefore, in in gdb, I set a breakpoint `b scheduler_tick` (called every 10ms).
However, when I printed out `p/x ((struct thread_info *)curr->stack)->cpu_context.pc`, I received the value as `$4 = 0x804d19d8`.

I expected the PC to be below `0x80000000` given that addresses above `0x80000000` are configured to be kernel-space in my kernel. Upon looking at the `objdump` output of the kernel, I see that the pc was pointing to `__schedule`.

Isn't the PC supposed to be pointing to user-space instructions for a process that I started from user-space?
My understanding was that, when an interrupt is triggered, the register state is saved, the interrupt is serviced, and then the register state is restored so the program continues as though 'nothing' happened.

Comment: See how ptrace does it, 
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/ptrace.c

Comment: There are multiple `PC` values.  The one you are looking at is the kernel `PC`.  The userspace one is in `struct task_struct *task`.  Using Auslen's link, `task_pt_regs((struct thread_info *)(curr)->task)->uregs[ARM_pc]` should get it.