# How to check macros defined in .so? I'd use nm to check the function, is there a way to do the same for macros?

Tags: c, linux, .so, nm

I have a code like this in mylib.h, and then I use it to create mylib.so.
Is there a way to check how MY_MACROS is defined in .so?

```
#ifdef SWITCH_CONDITION
    #define MY_MACROS       0
#else
    #define MY_MACROS       1
#endif
```

If that would be a function, I'd simply do

```
nm mylib.so | grep myfunction
```

Is there a way to do the same for macros?

P.S. There should be because of

```
> grep MY_MACROS mylib.so 
> Binary file mylib.so matches
```

Comment: Macros are not defined in dynamic libraries, they are compile-time (rather preprocessing time) only. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Macros are replaced by the preprocessor so they do not exist as symbols in the compiled code. In other words, in general it's not possible

Comment: @uneven_mark thank you ! I'm not sure if SWITCH_CONDITION works as it should and trying to figure out how to verify this.

Comment: Some of you make that into an answer.

Comment: macro definitions is lost information during compilation, you cannot, in general, see what compilation macros were defined and with what values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general there is no way to do this sort of thing for macros.  (But see more below.)

Preprocessor macros are theoretically a compile-time concept.  In fact, in the early implementations of C, the preprocessor was -- literally -- a separate program, running in a separate process, converting C code with `#include` and `#define` and `#ifdef` into C code without them.  The actual C compiler saw only the "preprocessed" code.

Now, theoretically a compiler *could* somehow save away some record of macro definitions, perhaps to aid in debugging.  I wasn't aware of any that did this, although evidently those using the [DWARF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) actually do!  See comments below, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757878/how-to-check-macros-defined-in-so-id-use-nm-to-check-the-function-is-there-a/57758747#57758747).

You can always write your own, explicit code to track the definition of certain macros.  For example, I've often written code elong the lines of

```
void print_version()
{
    printf("myprogram version %s", VERSION_STRING);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf(" (debug version)");
#endif
    printf("\n");
}
```

Some projects have rather elaborate mechanisms to keep track of the compilation switches which are in effect for a particular build.  For example, in projects managed by a [`configure`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) script, there's often a single file `config.status` containing one single record of all the compilation options, for posterity.

Comment: Note that you can `grep` the resulting binary to see if the macro name was defined if you compile with `-gdwarf-4 -g3`.

Comment: @SteveSummit The strange thing is that `grep MY_MACROS mylib.so` results in 
`Binary file mylib.so matches`. This macros should be somewhere! :) The problem is that `grep -a MY_MACROS mylib.so | less` and then direct search finds nothing.

Comment: @tkrishtop Aha! So it's looking like my "no" answer is wrong, and that the answer is actually "yes"!

Comment: @tkrishtop Yeah, you can use `-a` for that purpose. However, the value of the macro (if it's an integer) is stored in binary.

Comment: @JL2210 The problem is that `grep -a MY_MACROS mylib.so | less` and then direct search finds nothing.

Comment: @tkrishtop There's no way to do that. However, I *may* be able to write a tool that does the job. Give me a minute (or an hour) and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @JL2210 I was tempted to do the same thing!  You probably know this already, but before reinventing wheels, check the external links at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF .

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it requires debugging info.

You can compile your code with `-g3`:

```
$ gcc -g3 -shared -fPIC test.c -o test.so
```

and then run `strings` on the resulting binary:

```
$ strings test.so
...
__DEC32_EPSILON__ 1E-6DF
MY_MACROS 1
__UINT_LEAST32_TYPE__ unsigned int
```

Comment: Good catch. `-g3` is the key observation. `-g2` or below does not include macro definitions. (And also see questions like [gdb macro symbols not present even when using -g3 or -ggdb3 or -gdwarf-4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10496195/608639)).