# call setbuf(stdout, NULL): no symbol "NULL" in the current context

Tags: c, null, gdb

What should I do if I want to use identifier `NULL` in `gdb`'s call statement?

Is it because I didn't include stdio.h in gdb?

I have tried : `call #include <stdio.h>` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `0` or `(void*)0`. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 6):

`NULL` is a C define, defined somewhere as:

```
#define NULL ((void *) 0)
```

`NULL` is replaced by the C pre-processor to be `((void *) 0)`. So it's never passed to the compiler, so you can not use it in `gdb`.

So do as *Jester* suggested, and just use `(void *) 0`.

Comment: `NULL` can work with `-ggdb3` nowadays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31680508/895245

Answer (score 3):

Current GCC and GDB can see defines, but you must compile with `-ggdb3`, `-g` is not enough.

Input program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ABC 123

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

GDB:

```
# start is required.
start
print ABC
print NULL
```

Output:

```
$1 = 123
$2 = (void *) 0x0
```

Tested with GCC 4.8 and GDB 7.7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

See also: [How do I print a #defined constant in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934006/how-do-i-print-a-defined-constant-in-gdb)

Answer (score 0):

Above is good, also 0x0 should work for comparing pointers,
0x0 is the memory address that NULL points to. Here is an example I used while running gdb (on MS-DOS terminal) to print out memory addresses and see which were pointing to NULL for debugging a segmentation fault:
[image: console gdb printout of NULL pointer comparison]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).