# gdb get preprocessor macro info from file in different directory

Tags: c, gcc, macros, gdb

I'm trying to debug some additions I made to a fairly large c program using gdb.  The program I'm trying to debug makes extensive use of `#define` statements to set different values that are used throughout the code.  I need to be able to see what these values are in order to help my debugging (as they include some very important information.

After some digging around I found that the `info macro FOO` and `macro expand FOO` commands should be able to print these values if the `-g3` option (also tried the `-gdwarf-2` and `-ggdb3` flags as well) is passed to the compiler (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934006/how-do-i-print-a-defined-constant-in-gdb)).  However, whenever I try using this I get

```
The symbol `FOO' has no definition as a C/C++ preprocessor macro
at <user-defined>:-1
```

Now, I'm sure that the macro is defined otherwise the previous line of code would not have been able to run.  In addition, I'm certain that I have passed the `-g3` flag to the compiler.  I have one idea as to where the issue might be and that is the location that the macro is defined at.  Currently the macro is defined in a header file that is not in the same directory as the rest of the files (i.e. if the source files are in `/foo/bar/blam/..` then the macro is defined in `/def/mac/here/`.  Given this I thought maybe the problem was that gdb didn't know to look in this directory so I tried issuing the `directory` command in gdb and gave it the path to the directory containing the header file (base on [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html)).  This still did not solve the problem.

Does anyone know how I can get the values of these macros?  If it is pertinent I'm running gdb version 7.11 and compiling the program using 
`cc` and `gcc` both with `Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`.  Also, gdb was installed/built using homebrew.

Comment: Now you know why people are not all that enamoured of the C preprocessor.  It makes this sort of thing hard — for the debugger and the person doing the debugging.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I certainly understand.  This is actually one of my first forays into c programming so it's even more frustrating

Comment: Welcome to the Deep End.  Don't forget to surface to breathe.

Comment: My understanding is that `clang` doesn't yet emit macro debug info. (Despite the existence of a `gcc` command, if you run it you're actually running `clang`. You can install the original `gcc` with homebrew.)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  I tried switching out and using the `gnu gcc` (version 6.1.0) and still have the same problem.  Would I also need to switch to something else for `ranlib` and `ar` or can they stay the same as installed?

Comment: I don't know if ranlib or ar need to be the GNU versions.